# How to web scrape data with Selenium and BeautifulSoup and output to CSV file?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to Python and the Stack Overflow community as well. I am using selenium to web scrape https://freightliner.com/dealer-search/ for dealership names and addresses in North/South America and have been able to print it as a single string with no problems, but I cannot figure out how to export it to a csv file. The difference between the way that I am printing it in my code and how I want to export it to csv is that I am printing the name and address as a single string delimited by a semicolon whereas I want to export it to a csv as separate columns (name, address). The following is what I have tried:

```
'''
#! python3
# fl_dealers.py - Scrapes freightliner website for north american locations.

# import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time, os, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set Chrome options to automatically download file
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\\'}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)
chromedriver = 'C:/Users/username/chromedriver.exe'

# change directory to Downloads folder
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads")

# create webdriver object and call Chrome options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)

# maximize the browser window
browser.maximize_window()

# set wait time to allow browser to open
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

# open freightliner website
browser.get('https://freightliner.com/dealer-search/')

# maximize the browser window
browser.maximize_window()

time.sleep(5)

# find all locations in north america
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="by-location"]/div/div/input')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(search).click().key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("USA").perform()

#search.send_keys('USA')
search_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="by-location"]/button').click()

time.sleep(10)

# create variable for webpage AFTER searching for results
page_source = browser.page_source

# create bs4 object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

# create variables for dealer name and address
names = soup.find_all('h2')[1:]
addresses = soup.find_all(class_='address')

# print the names and addresses
for name, address in zip(names, addresses):
    print(name.get_text(separator="   ").strip(), ";", address.get_text(separator=", ").strip())
    
with open('fl_dealers.csv', mode='w', newline='') as outputFile:
    dealershipsCSV = csv.writer(outputFile)
    dealershipsCSV.writerow(['name', 'address'])
    
for name in names:
    dealer_name = name.get_text
    for address in addresses:
        dealer_address = address.get_text
        
dealershipsCSV.writerow([dealer_name, dealer_address])
'''
```

The code does create a CSV file, but it only creates the column headers and does not export any of the actual names and addresses. I have searched numerous stack overflow, github and youtube posts related to the issue, but have not been able to find a solution. I have reached the limit of my knowledge thus far. There is a high likelihood that I am missing something very simply. Alas, I am still new to Python.

One thing to note - The reasoning for entering "USA" in the search bar is to override the website's default of using my location to search for nearby dealers. Even though the query is for "USA", it returns all North/South American dealers which is what I want.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting we debug and end your work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main problem that you should append the names and addresses in a loop according to amount of data length.
Also you should use append mode, not write mode.
Please try this:

```
from csv import writer

with open('fl_dealers.csv', 'a') as outputFile:

    writer_object = writer(outputFile)

    for name, address in zip(names, addresses):
  
        writer_object.writerow(['name', 'address'])

    outputFile.close()
```